# Как отправить в laravel с помощью ajax?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Это мой код:

```
    <div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
          <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
            <p>Step 1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
            <p>Step 2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <form role="form" action="" method="post">
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3> Step 1</h3>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CourseId" class="control-label">{{__("Курсы")}}</label>
                    <select id="CourseId" name="CourseId" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%">
                        <option selected disabled>{{__("Выберите курсы")}}...</option>
                            @foreach($courses as $course)
                                <option value="{{$course->Id}}">{{$course->Title}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="answers" class="control-label">{{__('Число')}}</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-ground-prepend">
                        <input type="number"  class="form-control"  name="number" id="number" value="{{old("number")}}"   placeholder="{{__("Число")}}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h3> Step 2</h3>
              <input value="Завершить" type="submit"  class=" btn btn-primary" style="float: right;"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="answers" class="control-label">{{__('Название теста')}}</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-ground-prepend">
                        <textarea type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="title"
                                    id="editor"
                                    value="{{old("title")}}"
                                    placeholder="{{__("Название теста")}}"></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="demo"></div><br>
                <input value="Добавить ответ" type="button" onclick="msg()"  class=" btn btn-primary" style="float: right;"/>
                <div id="save">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="send()" type="button">Сохранить</button>
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
```

```
<!-- begining of page level js -->
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/31.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    var myClassicEditor;
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then(editor => {myClassicEditor = editor;})
        .catch(error => {console.error(error);})
</script>
<script>

    $.ajaxSetup( {
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
    });

    function msg()
    {
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.type = "text";
        x.name = "answers[]";
        x.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:15px");
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        demo.appendChild(checkbox);
        document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(x);
        const testElement = document.getElementById("demo");
        const lineBreak = document.createElement('br');
        testElement.appendChild(lineBreak);
    }

    function send()
    {
        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
url:"{{route('route.name')}}",
type:"POST"//или get
dataType:"JSON",
data:{
name:$('input[name=first_name]').val(),
},success:function(data){
console.log(data)
}
})
```

попробуйте так все просто